# Use ASP.NET Membership in ServiceStack

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, code-first, membership, servicestack

how can i use **asp.net membership** in [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) ? (ServiceStack.OrmLite , ServiceStack.Host.AspNet , etc )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can host ServiceStack on a [custom path](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#custompath), i.e. at /api which lets you run ASP.NET web forms and ServiceStack side-by-side and then use the normal ASP.NET membership provider in ASP.NET.

You can then share UserSessions with ServiceStack using its Session Provider, here's an example on how to [instantiate a Session with MVC](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/9183cdc31acd20a32e6ecbe645aed7a1251d32d2/NuGet/ServiceStack.Host.Mvc/content/App_Start/ControllerBase.cs.pp) - you can use this same class with ASP.NET.

The alternative is to forgo the ASP.NET membership provider and just stick to the [built-in authentication in ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization). It includes support for Credentials (i.e. user/pass - what you want) but also Twitter / Facebook / BasicAuth + your own. With In-Memory, OrmLite and Redis backends.

Here's an example website of using [all authentication options in the same ServiceStack app with an OrmLite backend](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/NuGet/ServiceStack.Host.Mvc/content/App_Start/AppHost.cs.pp#L16).

Comment: how can i use CredentialsAuthProvider for implementing **login form** ? is it possible for you to introduce a simple - and not a complicated - sample ?

Comment: See the example demo at: http://bootstrapapi.apphb.com and its source code at https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi

Comment: 404 on the instantiate a Session with MVC  link

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use membership, and want to use the ORM lite with the membership framework (although you could still use the SqlMembershipProvider), you can create a custom provider class like so:

```
public class ServiceStackMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{

}
```

And implement all the methods (or at least the methods you need) using the ORM components.